# Insert a matplotlib plot into a pdf file

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, base64, fpdf

I am trying by many ways to insert a plot from matplotlib into a pdf file using FPDF. The task would be easy just by saving the image into a file and inserting it into the pdf. All the same, I would like to insert the plot directly without saving it as a file. This question has been already done here at Stack but no one of the answers work for me. The next code shows some different approaches I have tried:

This code is just for the matplotlib plot:

```
with open('altitud.txt','r') as f:
    elevations = json.loads(f.read())
altitud_data = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(elevations))
x_data = [(0.269978*x) for x in range(0,len(altitud_data))]
plt.plot(x_data,altitud_data,color='green',lw=2)
plt.fill_between(x_data,altitud_data,facecolor="green")
plt.title('VISTA RUTA VERTICAL')
plt.xlabel('XX')
plt.ylabel('YY')
```

Firs Method:

```
with io.BytesIO() as output:
  plt.savefig(output, format="png")
  contents = output.getvalue()

im = Image.frombuffer("I;16", (5, 10), contents, "raw", "I;12")
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image(im,h=70,w=150,x=30,y=100,type="png")
pdf.output('imge_example.pdf','F')
```

Second Method:

```
import io
from PIL import Image

with io.BytesIO() as output:
  plt.savefig(output, format="png")
  contents = output.getvalue()

img = Image.frombytes("RGBA", (10, 10), contents)
outf = io.BytesIO()
img.save(outf, "PNG", optimize=True)
data = outf.getvalue()

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image(data,h=70,w=150,x=30,y=100,type="png")
pdf.output('imge_example.pdf','F')
```

Third Method:

```
import io
from PIL import Image

with io.BytesIO() as output:
  plt.savefig(output, format="png")
  contents = output.getvalue()

stream = BytesIO(contents)
image = Image.open(stream).convert("RGBA")

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image(image,h=70,w=150,x=30,y=100,type="png")
pdf.output('imge_example.pdf','F')
```

Finally using base64:

```
img = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(img, format='png')
img.seek(0)
base_64 = base64.b64encode(img.read())
img = base64.b64decode(base_64)

stream = BytesIO(img)
image = Image.open(stream).convert("RGBA")
stream.close()


pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image(image,h=70,w=150,x=30,y=100,type="png")
pdf.output('imge_example.pdf','F')
```

If anyone has any idea or any clue of how it can be done.

Comment: matplotlib can save figure into pdf directly..., using plt.savefig...

Comment: yes @ted930511 you are right...using PdfPages it is possible to save the image directly in a pdf file, but I would like to insert other information (texts, tables, etc) in the pdf

Comment: Andres how are you going to add that other information?  Most text processing tools allow you to include a PDF as a figure. Further there are PDF tools that allow you to insert pages into an existing PDF.  But without knowing the rest of your workflow it’s hard to advise.